# Matrix from counting coincindent values in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I really don't know how to define my request in words, so I really cant find if this has been answered or not, so please bear with me.

From this table of A#s (IRL will be much bigger):

```
A6  A7  A5          
A7  A8  A8          
A8  A9  A9          
A9
```

I want to create a matrix with the coincidences of A# on each column, this style:

|  | A5 | A6 | A7 | A8 | A9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| A6 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| A8 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| A9 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 |

Is there a way to combine formulas in excel to achieve this combination matrix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: this is from a schedule, and A# are people names, and as they work in shifts, i need to rotate teams 2x a year, so all members work will all members....the first table has the days, collumns 1, 2,3 and in which they work in the same shift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula in F2

```
=LET(data,$A$1:$C$4,
value1,$E2,
value2,F$1,
SUM(BYCOL(data,LAMBDA(c,--(SUMPRODUCT((value1<>value2)*((c=value1)+(c=value2)))=2)))))
```

[image]

`--(SUMPRODUCT(...))=2` returns 1 per each column where both values are present (but not equal).

Comment: Dunno what to say! Amazing, never thought somebody would even have a answer, let alone this fast! After 2 days fighting Bard and ChatGPT :D! You are the man IKE! Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I might have been to verbose, but try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=LET(arr,A1:C4,x,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(arr,3))),VSTACK(HSTACK("",TOROW(x)),HSTACK(x,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(x),ROWS(x),LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(--(BYCOL(arr,LAMBDA(l,ROWS(FILTER(l,(l=INDEX(x,r))+(l=INDEX(x,c)),""))>1)))))))))
```